# How does eslint control line breaks when multiple child elements are displayed

Tags: eslint, eslint-plugin-vue

I want to use `eslint` to achieve this effect without `prettier`

```
// before
<div><span>1</span><span>1</span></div>

// after
<div>
  <span>1</span>
  <span>1</span>
</div>
```